# Java generics in classes or interface - how do they help me?

Tags: java, generics

I came a cross this code:

```
public interface IOAttack<Client> {
    public void attack(Client c, Client victim);
    public void delayedHit(Client c, Client victim);
}

public class PlayerVictim implements AttackInterface<Client> {

 @Override
 public void attack(Client client, Client victim) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

 @Override
 public void delayedHit(Client client, Client victim) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

}
```

What is the purpose of adding  to the interface? I read about generics and all, arraylists, hashmaps etc, but I can't understand why are they there for exactly, what is the purpose of them.

How can this generic help me?

Comment: Did you read the tutorials at all? Recommended reading: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Comment: I think this example is misleading. `IOAttack<CLIENT extends SomeInterface>` makes more sense, but still does not explain why one would choose generics here instead of simply inheriting from `SomeInterface`.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that, in general, your generic type wouldn't be `<Client>` as in your example, but a non-existing class like `<E>` or perhaps `<? extends SomeClass>`. Then in your whole implementation, you can refer to this "temporary" type `E` as if it where a real class. Then you can reuse your implementation for all parameter types that fit `E`

Answer (score 0):

The generics can help restricting users of your API to  put the wrong type in your classes/collections.

in your example:

```
  public interface IOAttack<Client> {
         public void attack(Client c, Client victim);
         public void delayedHit(Client c, Client victim);
   }
```

I too can't see the utility, but if you change Client for T or T extends Client, then implementers of this interface would be able to use this interface with any type or only those types that extends(or implements) Client.

for example:

```
 public interface IOAttack<T> {
       public void attack(T victim);
        public void delayedHit(T victim);
   }
```

we could do the following:

```
public class PlayerVictim implements IOAttack<Dog> {

 @Override  public void attack(Dog victim) {   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

 @Override  public void delayedHit(Dog victim) {   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }
```

or

```
public class PlayerVictim implements IOAttack<Player> {

 @Override  public void attack(Player victim) {   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

 @Override  public void delayedHit(Player victim) {   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }
```

generics are a powerful way to create classes that attends to many different types .